# Can't install npm module telldus-core-js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

Hello I wounder if you could help me be able to build telldus-core-js on an raspberry pi.

I get the error below and cant figure out what i'm doing wrong.

The module I'm trying to install is this https://github.com/evilmachina/telldus-core-js with npm install telldus-core-js -g

```
>make: Entering directory /home/pi/piHomeAuto/node_modules/telldus-core-js/build'
>  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/telldus-core-js/telldus.o
>../telldus.cc:231:34: error: eio_req was not declared in this scope
>../telldus.cc:231:43: error: req was not declared in this scope
>../telldus.cc:231:48: error: expected , or ; before { token
>../telldus.cc:390:1: error: expected } at end of input
>make: *** [Release/obj.target/telldus-core-js/telldus.o] Fel 1
>make: Leaving directory /home/pi/piHomeAuto/node_modules/telldus-core-js/build'
>gyp ERR! build error
>gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
>gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit         (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
>gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:100:17)
>gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit         (child_process.js:789:12)
>gyp ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
>gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-                gyp/bin/node->gyp.js" "configure" "build"
>gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/piHomeAuto/node_modules/telldus-core-js
>gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.2
>gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
>gyp ERR! not ok
>npm ERR! weird error 1
```

Comment: It would appear telldus-core-js uses a native extension and it is having trouble building on your machine.  Trying searching their documentation/forums for compatible compiler versions/architectures, and see if anyone mentions anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Telldus-core-js does not work with 0.10.x version of Node.js (see this issue: https://github.com/evilmachina/telldus-core-js/issues/6). Use the [node-telldus fork](https://github.com/Hexagon/node-telldus) mentioned in the issue instead of telldus-core-js.